# How do I make my webtime tracking extension more efficient?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

this is the first project I'm working on, a Typescript-React chrome extension where a user can mark a website such as Reddit and they can view how long they spent on it. (it's not a unique idea, but it's something I want to code for experience).

The issue is I don't think I'm doing it very efficiently. The energy usage is really high when my extension is on, and I suspect it's consuming a lot of memory.

the **background** script is really simple:

```js
import {
  domainActivity,
  LocalStorage,
  LocalStorageKeys,
  setStoredSites
} from '.././utils/storage'
import { TabInfo } from '.././utils/api'
import { calculateDomain } from '.././utils/calculator'
import { PageEndData } from '.././contentScript/contentScript'


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  setStoredSites([
    "www.reddit.com",
    "twitter.com",
    "www.instagram.com"
  ])
  console.log("here")
})
```

I basically set a simple array of domains on startup that I want to monitor.

now the **contentScript** is where I think I'm messing it up:

```js
import { getStoredSites } from '.././utils/storage'
import { calculateDomain } from '.././utils/calculator'

export interface PageEndData {
    domain: string
    totalTimeSpent: number
}

getStoredSites().then((storedSites) => {
    const currentDomain = calculateDomain(window.location.href)
    const siteIncluded = storedSites.includes(currentDomain)

    if (!siteIncluded) {
        return
    }

    setTimeout(() => chrome.runtime.sendMessage("test"), 3000)


    let startTime: number = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
    let mouseEntered: boolean = false
    let totalTimeSpent: number = 0

    document.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        //we set up this if-else flow so that we can ignore the very first mouse entering
        if (!mouseEntered) {
            mouseEntered = true
        } else {
            //we create a new starttime if user enters the page again
            startTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
        }
    })

    document.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        const timeSpent = (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)) - startTime
        totalTimeSpent += timeSpent
    })


    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
        const data: PageEndData = {
            domain: "beforeunload",
            totalTimeSpent: totalTimeSpent + (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)) - startTime
        }
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data)
    })


})
```

On every page load, I get the array of stored sites, and check if the domain matches any inside the array.
If it does, then I begin loading some listeners to measure time spent with every mouse entering or leaving. If the tab closes or navigates to another page, I send the data over to the background script where I will calculate time spent and then store it (I haven't written this function yet)

Is this the most efficient way to do this? My chrome seems to be consuming a lot of energy when the chrome extension is running.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

Given that task, I am not sure I would have approached it the same way. Off the top of my head, I probably would have kept all of the logic within the background page/script and did something along the lines of:

- use a [non-persistent background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background)
- use [`browser.webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onCompleted) event to detect `enter` time
- use [`browser.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated) and [`browser.tabs.onRemoved`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onRemoved) to track `exit` time

When a `webNavigation.onCompleted` event happens on a tracked url, I would save the the `entrance` timestamp, `url` and `tabId`. Then I would listen for the aforementioned `browser.tab` events mentioned above for the `tabId` that is returned in the `details` object from the `webNavigation` event.

For the `browser.tab.onUpdated` you can check if the user nagivated to a different url from the `tabId` and for `browser.tabs.onRemoved` you can check if the user closes tracked `tabId` tab. If either of these occurs you can capture the `exit` timestamp, calculate the `duration` of the visit, save it, remove the event listener for that `tabId` and remove the save reference to the `entrance` time.

I don't think I would have worried about tracking events at the page level or even injecting a content script.

I am not sure how much more efficient this method would be, but maybe it will give you some ideas to simplify your code.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Just curious why did you specify that the background script be non-persistent?

Comment: @awks987 From what I understand a non-persistent background script reduces the extension resource "overhead", but also [it is best practice](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages/) to not use persistent background scripts unless you are using `browser.webRequest` api